# Progess chart in CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to build out this designed flow / progress chart in HTML/CSS/jQuery >

[image] and can't think how to make the various stacked rows include a down arrow and then a reversed arrow based on the direction of the previous row with the steps running from right to left, then left to right, then right to left etc...

This all needs to work responsively... I have it working in a traditional way as per code example here -

```js
function sortFlowChartArrows () {

/* clear prev arrow */

$('.arrow-right').each(function() {
$(this).remove();
});

$('.arrow-down').each(function() {
$(this).remove();
});


var windowWidthSize = $(window).width();

if (windowWidthSize >= 450) {

$('.projectStatusWrapper li:not(:last-child)').each(function() {
 $(this).after("<div class='arrow-right'></div>")
 
});

}

if (windowWidthSize <= 449) {

$('.projectStatusWrapper li:not(:last-child)').each(function() {
 $(this).after("<div class='arrow-down'></div>")
 
});

}

}

sortFlowChartArrows();

$(window).load(function() { sortFlowChartArrows(); });
$(window).resize(function() { sortFlowChartArrows(); });



/* PROJECT FLOW CHART - MAKE ALL LIS SAME HEIGHT */

function makeallflowchartLIsSameHeight () {

/* clear value */
$('.projectStatusWrapper li span').each(function() {
 $(this).css("height","")
})

var flowchartLIHeight = Math.max.apply( null, $(".projectStatusWrapper li").map( function () {
return $( this ).height();
}).get() );

console.log(flowchartLIHeight)

$('.projectStatusWrapper li span').each(function() {
 $(this).css("height",flowchartLIHeight+"px")
});
 
}


makeallflowchartLIsSameHeight();

$(window).load(function() { makeallflowchartLIsSameHeight(); });
$(window).resize(function() { makeallflowchartLIsSameHeight(); });
```

```css
.projectStatusWrapper {
width: 100%;
float: left; 
}
.projectStatusWrapper ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.projectStatusWrapper li {
display: inline-table;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
border: 2px solid #74b4df; 


-webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
margin: 0.5%;
font-weight: 400;
font-family: 'FFMarkWebProHeavy', Helvetica, Arial;

width: 17%;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
}
.projectStatusWrapper li span {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
padding: 15px 20px;
}
.projectStatusWrapper li.complete {
background-color: #74b4df;
color: #fff;
}
.arrow-right {
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-top: 15px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  
border-left: 15px solid #74b4df;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.arrow-left {
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-top: 15px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  
border-right: 15px solid #74b4df;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
float: right;
}
.arrow-down {
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-left: 15px solid transparent;
border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  
border-top: 15px solid #74b4df;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align:center;
  
position: relative;
left: 43.5%;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="projectStatusWrapper">

<ul>
<li class="complete">Step 1</li>
<li class="complete">Step 2</li>
<li>Step 3</li>
<li>Step 4</li>
<li>Step 5</li>
<li>Step 6</li>
<li>Step 7</li>
<li>Step 8</li>
<li>Step 9</li>
<li>Step 10</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Any ideas on how to make it work as per the design?

Comment: What are your constraints, if any? For instance, can you ues flexbox or CSS columns? (I don't know that they'd help, but if you can/can't use them, it would be good for people to know.)

Comment: No constraints - just need a good / intelligent mark up solution which works in a responsive manner to reflect the designed solution. I want to keep it as simple as possible though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this quite simple idea that **if we accept a fixed number of columns** actually works. Basically I put the arrow in `:after` and use `nth-child(6n+...)` to define the arrow case. Certainly needs some fine tuning, anyway [Codepen demo here](http://codepen.io/8odoros/pen/GqPdrR)

```css
.projectStatusWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.projectStatusWrapper ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.projectStatusWrapper li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 30.5%;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  border: 2px solid #74b4df;
  padding: 1%;
  margin: 1%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'FFMarkWebProHeavy', Helvetica, Arial;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.projectStatusWrapper li.complete {
  background-color: #74b4df;
  color: #fff;
}

.projectStatusWrapper li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.projectStatusWrapper li:nth-child(6n+4),
.projectStatusWrapper li:nth-child(6n+5),
.projectStatusWrapper li:nth-child(6n+6) {
  float: right;
}

.projectStatusWrapper li:nth-child(6n+1):after,
.projectStatusWrapper li:nth-child(6n+2):after {
  top: 50%;
  right: -19px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid tomato;
}

.projectStatusWrapper li:nth-child(6n+3):after,
.projectStatusWrapper li:nth-child(6n+6):after {
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -23px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: 15px solid tomato;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
}

.projectStatusWrapper li:nth-child(6n+4):after,
.projectStatusWrapper li:nth-child(6n+5):after {
  top: 50%;
  left: -19px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid tomato;
}

.projectStatusWrapper li:last-child:after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="projectStatusWrapper">
  <ul>
    <li class="complete">Step 1</li>
    <li class="complete">Step 2</li>
    <li>Step 3</li>
    <li>Step 4</li>
    <li>Step 5</li>
    <li>Step 6</li>
    <li>Step 7</li>
    <li>Step 8</li>
    <li>Step 9</li>
    <li>Step 10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - looks like that approach might work... but... the LI's are not following the new format of the arrows... I've just edited your HTML to use <li>step1</li> etc to make it more apparent what I mean - can we change the LI floats/directions on each row so they reflow to make sense?

Comment: Thanks - neat approach - nearly works apart from LIs sequence is wrong > see http://codepen.io/8odoros/pen/QEzmvZ?editors=1100 - can we use float:right to sort on even rows?

Comment: Fixed that, as well as the last arrow bug. Checked that with many different amounts of items and seems to work. Now I have to align them correctly...I updated the code with last changes.

Comment: Would your approach work in a responsive way so we could have more than 3 boxes in a row for large screens etc?

Comment: It will certainly work using `@media` to change the items `width` and `nth-child` styles appropriately but again with fixed values. Like 3 columns for mobile, 5 for tablet and 10 for big screens.

Comment: Yep - that was gonna be my approach. Thanks very much for your help here! Leg end!

Comment: I'll unabashedly ask if you have an idea for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744027/form-with-labelfield-units-wrappable-but-then-lining-up-nicely-when-wrapped). Note that I can't define fixed widths, but then I don't have funny arrows to worry about, either. ;-)

Comment: @8odoros - Just looking at nailing down the CSS to tighten this all up and cant work out why the boxes wont line up with each other in vertical columns... any ideas?